# Shanghai ascii game sticks

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, path-finding

Remove one stick and output the stack updated.

## Description

You can remove only sticks on top( completely drawn).

You can assume:

- there are 5 sticks on the table.
- there's one and only one stick you can remove.
- sticks are recognizable : there aren't overlapping sticks on the same orientation and there aren't sticks joined which form a longer line.
- input should be not ambiguous, there should be only one valid solution as pointed out by @Arnauld comment, for example [this input is not valid](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/a9Q86hhCgTVcCnUKCjUICiETA0XV3B@TmlJZn6egiEXkh6IWhiJZBRCvRGyejQtCgoKyLqA3P///wMA)
- Trailing /leading spaces doesn't matter.

Sticks are 4 chars long and are placed vertically or horizontally.

```
   |          ————
   |
   |  
   |
```

**Test cases**
[Before, after]

```
["      
 |||  
 —|—— 
 |||  
 |||— 
      ",
"      
 | |  
 ———— 
 | |  
 |—|— 
      "],
["       
 |||   
 —|——  
 |||   
 |||—— 
       
       ",
"       
 | |   
 ———— 
 | |   
 |—|—— 
       
       "],
["        
 |||    
 —|——   
 |||    
 |||——— 
        
        ",
"        
 | |    
 ————   
 | |    
 | |——— 
        
        "],
["       
    |  
 ———|  
 |———  
 |  |  
 |———— 
       ",
"       
    |  
 ———|  
 |———  
 |  |  
 |     
       "],
["          
   |      
   |      
   |      
  ————    
  | |     
  | |     
  |———    
    |     
          ",
"          
   |      
   |      
   |      
  ||      
  | |     
  | |     
  |———    
    |     
          "],
["         
         
   |     
  ————   
   ——|—  
   |———  
     |   
         
         
         ",
"         
         
   |     
   | |   
   ——|—  
   |———  
     |   
         
         
         "],
["        
        
 | |    
 ————|  
 | |——— 
 | | |  
     |  
        
        ",
"        
        
 | |    
 | | |  
 | |——— 
 | | |  
     |  
        
        "],
["         
         
 ———|    
  ——|—   
   —|——  
    |——— 
         
         
         ",
"         
         
 ————    
  ————   
   ————  
    ———— 
         
         
         "],
["         
   |     
  —||—   
   ||    
  ————   
  | |    
  |      
  |      
         ",
"         
   |     
  —||—   
   ||    
  |||    
  | |    
  |      
  |      
         "],
["        
        
 |——— | 
 |  | | 
 |  | | 
 ———| | 
        
        ",
"        
        
 |———   
 |  |   
 |  |   
 ———|   
        
        "]
```

**Input specifications**
You can add trailing and leading whitespaces / lines as your wish, , I hope this can help focusing on the task by avoiding data bounds checking.

[here is a small program](https://tio.run/##xVbJjtNAEL3XV5R8SeweIgbBcMqNOweOSYTswcMYJU5kG5GIjsRH8IX8SOglvXdnGYFiJXK7uuvV63rVS/e92h36oWvarx/qZbNqhrqbYjbPMii7Tps@L5FZZ56x48ZFBo/PpbEiN85HGTTtl7od@BeyIevVquTtuwza@seyaWsxrs0OQ90P/XQGswzFA0gp5a8/v35T9mc/Y2Mv@S2e7A7AeKHy0j9jpUcw7blgrjqkwneDWlYZ1vLXb4uCipYgYbGIAjFGmo8O7TGy7ZqTjWYaNjFNwafm9FA8DeinjD1uxnWmrQQielYbnHF8IdyJ1Ek7PdP00sBN1MDaTX8YetH9XF8Wn1rNl8flklgzhwiFcK6875jhY1rRS7MKBgnk2KwTsXXt/6OY7ozhTIHTSF1TtSfoijuzdMIQGuJ6aMaffaZEs4lb0lFHOOokLbZmr5QrshaSJePEji7qi4QLCpRac6Q0yUJLYC@l8zM9G4ma1kURvM3alIjhS9V@5TQshek1pefv2epEQf/EoRivuwUc2PbND/CPT5/Egd@zE1gcvpNVuflJBwo4yOaO4m7Sb5bNMB7BKN/DHmDDXAZ2kiNDKHe4fkJ5begZYRd2UpePzxJPOsmbQPGOoHunAKymr3lQ6bBlDq7HQ1Gh78QM3n0FmYlsJ9/WTTsO@gjKqwdBde0gCv19DCqP43v3HoISthhX0/tXVW7gi4qvb9yruQeOws@wASu385bdh0hWZMX9GyK/uGRh5kWj5y1@9RIKOHl7G8saJExGN10G/kBdGEKisBe3qm54wbnXQSKKUJUTjkaYS6mcYUQ4SqWcjhxJiMkh90fBE8oQLbeltss8D3SFNGqyih7CXAvOHgKkkD22erHEYQNe3gROllJYSLconxvWSqoy8psJHwP@H9LD4S8) to get input data in some formatting.  In the header section you can change some characters like array bounds and others.
Data is in the form of a square matrix and the image is surrounded by whitespaces.

## Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT, return it as a function result or error message/s.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24336/84844)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 102 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υιυ≔ΦＬυ№§υι×-⁴η≔Σηζ¿η‖Ｔ↗«≔Ｅθ⭆υ§λκυ≔ΣΦＬυ№§υι×|⁴ζ»Ｊζ⌕§υζ×§-|¬η⁴Ｆ⁴↓§ -⊙ＥＥrlＫＤχ✳κ…κ⌕Ｅκ›μ ⁰∧›⁵Ｌκ№κ-¿η‖Ｔ↗
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFda8IwFH22v@LSpwRScOBe9KkoDsc2RN0PKDW2oWnSpemczv327qYfVgZjLJBycnpO7rk3cRqZWEeyro@pkBzIShWV3VojVEIohXVVpqRiIOjMWyNpSYUoLEuRKLIU0nJDnrhKLKoog7muUBLaldrzj9bHYCdyXhI/8BlMKEUiHa7YVjlJkTojJQ6AGDb8IHlsdyZS5UGbnExfi41IUosSLksOn96ocz9HBXlj0MZ1B6zYF5cMsqaaCzy6Kfe/1Jdrahfxy3us8mKnyZnBUqj9rel8NfWkHzj3i7bYFm2vmXnYEpAJTraZ5nShj2oI7YObUqhOTWtu@0Yis@Y8WwiDYxFakbsxg@HUdjk/xZLPU12QrIvm3IgfDI9cvzkDH3wnHbtPiIr@1z2DbhoZvY4DrfhklDah/36augaACzTL@w0GuDp46egfcBD0Pq8O3uU3) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of strings containing spaces, minus signs or pipes. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the game.

```
υ
```

Output the game to the canvas.

```
≔ΦＬυ№§υι×-⁴η≔Σηζ
```

Try to locate a horizontal stick.

```
¿η
```

If one was found, then...

```
‖Ｔ↗
```

... reflect the canvas transforming between minus signs and pipes, ...

```
«
```

Otherwise, ...

```
≔Ｅθ⭆υ§λκυ
```

... transpose the game array (sadly without transforming), ...

```
≔ΣΦＬυ№§υι×|⁴ζ
```

... and find a vertical stick.

```
»Ｊζ⌕§υζ×§-|¬η⁴
```

Jump to the stick's current location on the canvas.

```
Ｆ⁴↓§ -⊙ＥＥrlＫＤχ✳κ…κ⌕Ｅκ›μ ⁰∧›⁵Ｌκ№κ-
```

Overwrite the pipes of the (possibly transformed) stick with spaces, unless there are at most four consecutive non-blank characters (including the pipe itself) including at least one minus sign on at least one side of the pipe, in which case overwrite with a minus sign instead.

```
¿η‖Ｔ↗
```

Transform the canvas back if necessary before it's implicitly printed.

Comment: [Fail](https://tio.run/##jVDBTsMwDD2vX2H15EiJBGgnOE1ISJtgqrbCveqyNlqalDZhaJRvL267dRUHxCGO8/Ke/ew0T6rUJrptj7nSEnBpSu@2rlImQ8Yg8nWOnoNiD0FEoENP2aKuVWbwSWknK3yWJnPEYhwerSfKwi3NTn4OOg6xKmSNoQg5zBkjIL@W2PoCc4JOBO1tBbi2jgAGX8FsI/dapi6uElPTX4H3r@VGZbkj7uysf0lKfOcwGO4e1PPSvuCg@35@Iuga/sP34eq7GX13Jr@DlS/K2FIRs5sqTqPiAoaik54H6mtM5pzTbvt9jmxoOvrgZGUVWdUqlRhJeXizZi19kRiDVOOGwy2dO0qPdMggufu1vj9217YA0EAghKDY0EWxR7pcBK340D8) it turns into a 5 char long stick

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks; I've implemented a completely different algorithm now.

Comment: I want try [this](https://tio.run/##jVHBbsIwDD2vX2H1lEipxCR2gVMFYmLaJgTsA6oSmqhp0qXpGKz79s4p0HKYtFVqZL/42c8vqUhsahLVtgchFQey1GXtNs5KnRFKYVVXgtQMJJ0GKwQdqTGKq0pmmiykctySZ64zh1WUwczUWBK7pd7xzzOPwVYWvCJhFDIYU4qAGFps6oIIhE4IyT1gDGu@Vzx1W5voam9sQSZv5VpmwmEJVxWHr@Duwn5JSvLO4CzXJzjxOrxgoLppXvDdzbh/qM4H1U2v2kv8Dp7qotwacmKwkHp3Szr1pCsYRp79ahyuRc9tpgGuBGSMznZuTubmoAfRIXiXYn3sVvN/aBUiK87zubRoizSa3I8YDFneqZsdU8VnwpQkv0jzbIwfLU/8vuhHCKEvHfkjxorr1QODixs57e1AKj4ZpZ3ov5@mbeHmC/zRNM2QRE0U/X6DyXDTN2ijD/UD) testcase, but I don't know how to make it work. Should I padding some more spaces around?

Comment: @tsh Sorry, I got bit by Charcoal behaviour. It's very difficult to use `if` because the `else` is implicit (verbose mode lets you drop the else but it's still there really) so if I don't want an `else` then I use a `for` loop instead, but then that reallocates the implicit `for` variables... anyway, should be fixed now.